# Form Validation and HTTP Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, jquery-forms-plugin

A form is submitted using jQuery form plug-in to an action in MVC framework. In the action, if form validation fails a reply should be sent back to the client. jQuery form plug-in comes with error and success callbacks (like any other jQuery Ajax functions).
Isnt it a better practice to return an HTTP Exception with error-code 400 (Bad Request) and catch it in error callback rather than returning a successful HTTP response and catching it in success callback?

If the answer is yes, wouldn't it be more descriptive to have data attached to HTTP Exception?
From what I see right now, `HTTPException.Data` is readonly. One of the constructors seems to do the job (`HttpException(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)`) but I cant wrap my head around it.
Would someone please explain for me how to add data to HTTP Exception?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not better practice to simply return an error code, even if you do manage to attach messages to the HTTPException.

Why?  Well, you lose so much information that way.  You have the option to return an arbitrary JSON object, which could include (for example) a list of all validation errors (or indeed, any pertinent info which may help the calling client out), which you then render on the client so that the user is able to correct.

Also, you've got to consider what happens when your call is successful.  Is a 200 return code really enough for your purposes?

Comment: The Http Response code is what confuses me. Correct me if I am wrong but what I understand from 200 is that the request is processed successfully. I mean if there is an error function call back isn't it better to make a good use of it?

Comment: It's not an HTTP exception that you're trying to report. It's a form validation error. So as Paul implies return HTTP OK, but include data in your HTTP response pertaining to the validation error. Look at MVC's JsonResult which inherits ActionResult.

Comment: Whether your data is valid or not, it's better for your endpoint to complete successfully, return a 200 and include data which indicates why validation failed.

Comment: @tomtroughton: Thanks for the advice, but my problem is more philosophical in nature. Isn't it better to use `HttpException`, considering the fact that error callbacks will be called if and only if an exception happens?

Comment: I found this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639931/asp-net-mvc-httpexception-message-not-shown-on-client). "if you want to access strings and stuff you should return JSON objects and not throw any exceptions. You should choose which of two you want: either a fully RESTFul API in which the status code is sufficient and allows you to imply the errors message or return JSON objects. – Darin Dimitrov"

Comment: I feel you're misunderstanding the point of an HttpException. It is used to describe an exception that occurred during the _processing_ of an HTTP request. Your request is processing fine, hence you should return 200 OK. Your form failing to validate is an entirely different aspect. You'd be misappropriating the HttpException class.