# What is the point of HttpException in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http

I'm a little bit confused with the HttpException Exception class in ASP.NET MVC 4. I understand it lets you throw custom error codes, but there's also another constructor that accepts a message:

[HttpException Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8wx71y3(v=vs.110).aspx)

As I understand, HTTP only sends back status codes and a small message related to the status code like 'Internal Server Error'. If this is the case, what is even the point of using this class in the context of an ASP.NET MVC app? Right now I have controllers which throw HttpExceptions with specific status codes to tell the client what is going on. Is this the right approach?  Example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// GET: Returns the data required for the modal to edit the environments.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditEnvironments()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Setting> settings = _service.GetAllSettings().ToList();
            return PartialView("_EditEnvironments", settings);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            throw new HttpException(500, "Something bad happened.", ex);
        }
    }
```

Here the message "Something bad happened." will never be shown to the client. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Erm, where did you get the idea HTTP sends back only status codes? How would state "OK" then work?

Comment: There's no point of doing so, the MVC application handles HTTP status codes. `HttpException` is generally used when you make a web service call or use `HttpWebRequest` or `HttpWebResponse` for whatever reason

Comment: I understand that there is a status code and a small message like 'OK' as I wrote in my second paragraph. And Fourat - thanks.

Comment: protected void Application_Error() in global.asax.cs ---- HttpException ex = exception as HttpException; ex.GetHttpCode() == 404. I use this for custom redirects from a .csv file.

Comment: Within the construct of a web api it can be useful to use specific response types to then be handled differently by the front end app.  For example, an HTTP 400 (Bad Request) would probably be handled differently from an HTTP 403 (Forbidden).

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on the comments it turns out that it's pointless in an ASP.NET MVC app with just a client and server. It's useful for two web APIs to talk to each other. However, if anyone is interested you want to 'pass' a message to the client in the context of ASP.NET MVC, you can use the HttpStatusCodeResult like this:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500,"Something bad happened")
```

And you can access "Something bad happened" using, say, jQuery $.ajax() like this:

```
                    $.ajax: {
                        url: "@Url.Action("RequestsAdminAjax", "Admin")",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: function(data) { return JSON.stringify(data); },
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        error: function (xhr, textStatus,errorThrown) {
                            debugger;
                            toggleAlert('<strong>Error: </strong>Unable to load data.', 'alert alert-danger');
                        }
                    },
```

and `errorThrown` will contain "Something bad happened".

Hopefully this helps someone.